# Why is ZLib not appending the adler32 and length fields to compressed data?

Tags: c, api, compression, zlib

I've got a problem with my usage of the ZLib API. My data is correctly compressed and decompressed again, but the `::inflate()` (decompression) side is never returning with `Z_STREAM_END`, only `Z_OK` (*which is not how it should be, according to the docs and the ZLib source code*).

Here's what I'm doing to compress:

```
// (set up a `z_stream` with `data_type` as `Z_BINARY`)
call `::deflate(..., Z_NO_FLUSH)` to compress chunks until no more input left
call `::deflate(..., Z_FINISH)` until it returns `Z_STREAM_END` (it does!)
```

Later, I'm doing the same with `::inflate()`:

```
// (set up a `z_stream` with `data_type` as `Z_BINARY`)
call `::inflate(..., Z_NO_FLUSH)` to decompress chunks until no more input left
call `::inflate(..., Z_FINISH)` until it returns `Z_STREAM_END` (never happens).
```

What happens is that `::inflate(..., Z_NO_FLUSH)` consumes all input and produces the full decompressed stream(!), while still only returning `Z_OK`.

---

At this point, `z_stream::state` is still `CHECK` ([inflate.c, line #1198](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f/inflate.c#L1197) - wants to read 32 bits for adler32 checksum), then `z_stream::state` should be set to `LENGTH` ([inflate.c, line #1221](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f/inflate.c#L1221) - want to read another 32 bits for stream length) and finally `z_stream::state` should be set to `DONE` which gives the expected `Z_STREAM_END` return value ([inflate.c, line #1235](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f/inflate.c#L1234)).

However, the 32 bits for the adler32 checksum and the 32 bits for the stream length are never appended by `::deflate()`. Am I missing something or using ZLib wrongly?

---

**UPDATE: as requested, the compression code in detail**

```
// Initialization
this->stream.msg = nullptr;
this->stream.state = nullptr;
this->stream.zalloc = &allocate; // delegates to malloc() (Z_SOLO)
this->stream.zfree = &free; // delegates to free() (Z_SOLO)
this->stream.data_type = Z_BINARY;

int result = ::deflateInit(&this->stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
// error handling performed here

// ...

while(input_data_available) {

  this->stream.next_in = uncompressedBuffer;
  this->stream.avail_in = static_cast<uInt>(uncompressedByteCount);
  this->stream.next_out = outputBuffer;
  this->stream.avail_out = static_cast<uInt>(outputByteCount);

  int result = ::deflate(&this->stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
  // error handling performed here
  
}

do {

  this->stream.next_in = nullptr;
  this->stream.avail_in = 0;
  this->stream.next_out = outputBuffer;
  this->stream.avail_out = static_cast<uInt>(outputByteCount);

  int result = ::deflate(&this->stream, Z_FINISH);
  // error handling performed here

} while(this->stream.avail_out == 0);

assert(result == Z_STREAM_END);
```

Comment: I can't really tell anything from your tiny code particles. You'd need to show at least the part of your compression code showing the loop and how you write the data. It sounds like you are not writing all what deflate is delivering.

Comment: @MarkAdler Or if all is being written at some level, perhaps some of it is still stuck in a buffer (e.g. a stdio FILE needing to be `fflush`ed or something).

Comment: @MarkAdler I added a condensed of the actual calls I'm making to the question. Here's the actual, running code: https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/browse/filedetails.php?repname=Framework&path=/storage/Nuclex.Storage.Native/trunk/Source/Compression/ZLib/DeflateCompressor.cpp&rev=2938

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm compressing an artificially generated pattern into an in-memory buffer and then decompressing it again, so no flushing or file buffers involved in this case.

Comment: Good thing you provided a link to the actual code, since what you put in the question has made-up stuff that isn't in your actual code. There are no loops of any kind in the actual code, yet you put in a while and do-while in the question.

Comment: Also you use `delflateInit2()` in the actual code, whereas you claim to use `deflateInit()` in the code in the question. Therein lies at least part of your problem.

Comment: What I posted here on SO is the actual code. The `Process()` and `Finish()` methods are called in just such loops, but I assumed posting a 1000 line, multi-method reproduction case would not help. Sorry for leaving the `deflateInit2()` in my linked code, it was an attempt to see how this would affect `deflate()` - namely, the trailer check. All tests were done with `deflateInit()` as it can be seen above the `// Testing...` comment.

Comment: The loops make no sense as written. You would be reading concatenations of the same input buffer, and then overwriting the same output buffer.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

The code that you *linked* has:

```
int result = ::deflateInit2(
&this->stream, level, Z_DEFLATED, -MAX_WBITS, MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY
);
```

The `-MAX_WBITS` requests a raw deflate stream, with no header or trailer. The reason you are not getting a trailer is because you requested that there not be a trailer.

As an aside, your question talks about an Adler-32 field and a length field. Those never go together. Either you request the zlib format (with `MAX_WBITS`), which has only an Adler-32 in the trailer, or you request the gzip format (with `MAX_WBITS+16`), which has a *CRC-32* and a length field.

Comment: OP's decompression code [here](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/browse/filedetails.php?repname=Framework&path=%2Fstorage%2FNuclex.Storage.Native%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FCompression%2FZLib%2FDeflateDecompressor.cpp&peg=2938) is using `inflateInit` so I'm surprised it got as far as it did. Doesn't it expect a zlib header in the stream?

Comment: Yes, it would fail at not seeing a zlib header. The report the OP made in the question of decompressing the data cannot be consistent with the code that was linked. The OP is confused, sloppy, or something, mixing up code and reported results. Not to mention posting pseudo-code inconsistent with the actual code.

Comment: Sorry for the mismatch in the linked code, I have inserted `deflateInit2()` to see how it would affect my problem. The issue itself is happening with `deflateInit()` (and the default, positive window bit count), the way I described it in the super-condensed and less-condensed code.

Answer (score -1):

Self-answer: As I stated in my question, I was wondering: *Am I missing something or using ZLib wrongly?*

As in: did I overlook an `appendTrailer()` method or some `Z_FINISH | WITH_TRAILER` option that I need to add?

The answer to that question is no. Pumping data with `deflate(..., Z_NO_FLUSH)` and then calling `deflate(..., Z_FINISH)` until no more output is pending **will** write the trailer.

---

This means (considering ZLib is one of the most battle-tested compression libraries out there) my code must damage or truncate the compressed data stream somehow.

It would now fall upon me to build a runnable reproduction case, but it was never my intention to have the SO community debug my code for me (thanks @Mark Adler himself for trying, though!). Just to verify whether my usage of the ZLib API, shown in pseudo code above, was correct and complete.